# Contact Form 7 hide label of empty field

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 in a Wordpress site. I have a couple of non-required fields that have labels next to them in the email I am sending. For example..

In the form:

Origin City or Airport Code[text origin-city3]

So in the email:
    Origin City: [origin-city3]

I need 'Origin City: [origin-city3]' to not display if the user did not input a value in the form for origin-city-3 since it is not required.

I have a pretty good understanding of jquery, but do not know if I can use that in the output email.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code? Without seeing what you're working with, can't provide a legitimate answer.

Comment: [Check this](http://www.fastsecurecontactform.com/modify-email-fields-before-export), could be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been years but I want to help others just in case they are looking for the same answer.

You can check the "Exclude lines with blank mail-tags from output" option in the Mail Tab.